# Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers not working

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, http-headers

Even though I've added this in my .htaccess file:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

And this in my apache config: (Inside a  section AND outside)

```
<Files ~ "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|json|xml)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Files>
```

It still does not work!

When I get the DIRECTORY it does give me the wanted header, but as soon as I download a specific file the header is nowhere to be found!

How hard can it be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains may help.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|json|xml)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```